# How to prove invertible matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove invertible matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: Do you have a reason for thinking this is generally true?

Answer (score 5):

Your statement is false.

Consider the example
\begin{align}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 1\\
0 &1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which is invertible but not diagonalizable.